# Reading a sequence file into pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in hdfs which I need to serialize and write to orc. I have copied the data using the copytolocal method in hdfs, and I have it in the file system.

I am trying to somehow read the seq file into spark,either directly from hdfs or from the staging area (where I'd just use copytolocal).

I would like to firstly just be able to read the data and print out the first few rows, to see that they are formatted correctly. I have the schema in a csv file, the schema is very simple:
columnA;STRING - just one column.

The first line of the seq file is:

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text^Yorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text^A^A*org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec
```

Here's what I tried:

```
    Using Python version 3.9.12 (main, May 25 2022 11:45:19)
    
    Spark context Web UI available at http://njdfkbdfa
    
    Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local\[\*\], app id = local-43525254).
    
    SparkSession available as 'spark'.
    
    input_path = "file:///path/to/my/file.seq"
    
    file_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_path)
    
    for file_path, content in file_data.collect():
    
        print(f"File: {file_path}")
        
        print("Content:")
        print(content\[:1000\])
```

Error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1197, in collect
        sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : java.io.IOException: Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:134)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:102)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:81)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
            at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileInputFormat.setMinPartitions(WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala:52)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.WholeTextFileRDD.getPartitions(WholeTextFileRDD.scala:54)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
            at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
            at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

    >>> input_path = "file://path/to/my/file.seq"
    >>> file_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_path)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 817, in wholeTextFiles
        self._jsc.wholeTextFiles(path, minPartitions),
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
        raise converted from None
    pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://path/to/my/file.seq, expected: file:///
    >>> input_path = "file://path/to/my/file.seq"
    >>> input_path = "file:///path/to/my/file.seq"
    >>> file_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_path)
    >>> for file_path, content in file_data.collect():
        print(f"File: {file_path}")
        print("Content:")
        print(content[:1000])  # Displaying only the first 1000 characters
    ... ... ... ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1197, in collect
        sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/etl/airflow2.4.2/venv_3.9.12_airflow_2.4.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : java.io.IOException: Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:134)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:102)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:81)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
            at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileInputFormat.setMinPartitions(WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala:52)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.WholeTextFileRDD.getPartitions(WholeTextFileRDD.scala:54)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
            at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
            at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
            at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I don't really understand why kerberos would be a problem here, as I am not trying to read it directly from hdfs. The file is on the same machine that spark runs on (it's a single machine, not a cluster). I just run venv and open spark.

I tried all other questions on stackoverflow referring to pyspark and sequence files, but none of them seems to refer to my problem.

I know these questions are rather lame, but I'm just starting out and google didn't help.

Comment: I think Spark need to write some temp file to HDFS. Did you renew the Kerberos ticket (using kinit -k -t ....) before running pyspark?

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 Yes, I did kinit and tried hdfs dfs -ls etc, I have the access, then I open pyspark and still face the same problem.